# PHP Date difference , save each day between in array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array which each element contains a startdate and enddate formated in 'dd.mm.yy'.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] =
            (
                [date_start] = 23.07.2014
                [date_end] = 02.08.2014
            )
     )
```

Now i need to build an array that will contain every day between date_start and date_end to validate them later.

Now my question is how can i calculate every day between those dates  and save it to an array ?

Comment: Can you also post required output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2014-05-01');
$endDate  = new DateTime('2014-06-02');
 // calculate diff
$diff = $startDate->diff($endDate);
$daysDiff = $diff->days;


for ($i = 0; $i < $daysDiff; $i++) {
    // clone so the original date will not be changed
    $currentDate = clone $startDate;
    $currentDate->modify('+'.$i.' days');
    echo $currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
}
```

Now you only have to make this for every array entry and save it to an array

Comment: You need to change format of date's before make this, maybe this code can help you:
[code]
$newformat = explode(23.07.2014)
$strDate = "$newformat[2]-$newformat[1]-$newformat[0]"
[/code]

Answer (score 2):

**IF YOU JUST WANT DATE DIFFERENCE**

```
<?php
        $arr=array
        (
            array
                (
                    'date_start' =>'23.07.2014',
                    'date_end' =>'02.08.2014'
                ),
            array
            (
                'date_start' =>'15.07.2014',
                'date_end' =>'02.08.2014'
            )
         );

         foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
            $diff=strtotime($val['date_end'])-strtotime($val['date_start']);
            $new_arr[]=array(
                                'day_start'=>$val['date_start'],
                                'day_end'=>$val['date_end'],
                                'difference'=>$diff/(24*60*60)-1
                            );  
         }
         print_r($new_arr);
    ?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day_start] => 23.07.2014
            [day_end] => 02.08.2014
            [difference] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day_start] => 15.07.2014
            [day_end] => 02.08.2014
            [difference] => 17
        )

)
```

**IF YOU WANT ALL DATE BETWEEN ARRAYS**

```
<?php
    $arr=array
    (
        array
            (
                'date_start' =>'23.07.2014',
                'date_end' =>'02.08.2014'
            ),
        array
        (
            'date_start' =>'15.07.2014',
            'date_end' =>'02.08.2014'
        )
     );

     foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        $diff=strtotime($val['date_end'])-strtotime($val['date_start']);
        $day_diff=$diff/(24*60*60);
        $alldiff=array();
        for($i=1;$i<=$day_diff-1;$i++){

            $alldiff[]=date('d.m.Y',(strtotime($val['date_start'])+$i*24*60*60));
        }
            $new_arr[]=array(
                                'day_start'=>$val['date_start'],
                                'day_end'=>$val['date_end'],
                                'difference'=>$alldiff
                            );  

     }
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($new_arr);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day_start] => 23.07.2014
            [day_end] => 02.08.2014
            [difference] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 24.07.2014
                    [1] => 25.07.2014
                    [2] => 26.07.2014
                    [3] => 27.07.2014
                    [4] => 28.07.2014
                    [5] => 29.07.2014
                    [6] => 30.07.2014
                    [7] => 31.07.2014
                    [8] => 01.08.2014
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day_start] => 15.07.2014
            [day_end] => 02.08.2014
            [difference] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16.07.2014
                    [1] => 17.07.2014
                    [2] => 18.07.2014
                    [3] => 19.07.2014
                    [4] => 20.07.2014
                    [5] => 21.07.2014
                    [6] => 22.07.2014
                    [7] => 23.07.2014
                    [8] => 24.07.2014
                    [9] => 25.07.2014
                    [10] => 26.07.2014
                    [11] => 27.07.2014
                    [12] => 28.07.2014
                    [13] => 29.07.2014
                    [14] => 30.07.2014
                    [15] => 31.07.2014
                    [16] => 01.08.2014
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert dates into timestamp, then you loop from the timestamp_start until timestamp_end , by day amount of seconds, then you convert each steps into a new date to check later.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// Convert start and end dates to unix timestamp
$start = strptime($date_array[0]['date_start'], '%d.%m.%Y');
$end = strptime($date_array[0]['date_end'], '%d.%m.%Y');

$dates = array();
while ($start < $end){
  $dates[] = date('d.m.Y', $start);
  $start += 86400 // One day equals 86400 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as it is working for me

```
function getDates($startTime, $endTime) {
$day = 86400;
$format = 'd.m.Y';
$startTime = strtotime($startTime);
$endTime = strtotime($endTime);
$numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day);  

$days = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays; $i++) { 
    $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));
}

return $days;
```

}

$days = getDates('23.07.2014', '02.08.2014');